# What is run_init and load::om in php

Tags: php, xhprof

In profiler I see the following

```
load::om/BaseApplicationsQuery.php  1   0.0%    807 0.5%    807 0.5%    1,250   2.0%    1,250   2.0
load::map/DeviceApplicationsTableMap.php    1   0.0%    2,636   1.8%    2,636   1.8%    0   0.0%    0   0.0%
```

What does it mean load::om, load::map, run_init?

Comment: `load` is class and `om` is static function or variable.

Comment: You might want to checkout http://xhprof.io that explains all of the XHProf data. Disclaimer – I am the author of this open source product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those prefixes load:: are added with xhprof module when zend_compile_file is called and run_init is php require or include.